# hash in href in web source

Tags: javascript, html, web, href

I have simple question. [This website](http://www.racingpost.com/horses/seasonal_stats_home.sd#seasonStatsTabs=trainer_seasonal_stats) shows my problem. Look for web source and find line similar to:

```
<a href="#">Next</a>
```

Where does # redirect if I click Next on this site?

---

Basicly i like to get all data from all pages on that site which shows statistics. I have to use C# and i still dont know how to navigate through this javascript pages

Comment: There's some Javascript that handles the `Next` functionality, the `#` (in this case) prevents the page from loading another page/link, but will still appear/act as a link style-wise.

Answer (score 3):

`#` is a relative URI to the top of the current page.

In this case, it is probably being used as a "I can't be bothered to use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)" hack for a link that will have a JavaScript event handler attached to it.

For further reading see [fragment identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/intro.html#h-2.1.2) and [how to create anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

A link href preceaded with # leads to an Anchor on the same page.
Since the href is "#" it will lead to the top of the page..

This is usually used to jump between places in the same page.

In the case of the link you provided, the "#" is used to have an `A` tag bound to a javascript click event without visiting the link in the href .

Comment: # is the top of the page, not 'nowhere'.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on it, it will lead you to the top of the page (in this case).